# Titanium 64-bit Support for Stream Specs

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

There seems to be a problem with the 64-bit version of the Titanium Stream Specs. I am getting the following stack trace error:

```
Script Error Couldn't find module: stream for architecture: arm64
Script Error Module "libs/backendless.js" failed to leave a valid exports object
ErrorController is up. ABORTING showing of modal controller
Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
at ClientRequest.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/request/request.js:819:19)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:679:10)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:352:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
<p class="p1">---------------------------------------------
at Request.init (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/request/request.js:190:10)
at new Request (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/request/request.js:130:8)
at request (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)
at Function.get (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/request/index.js:62:12)
at _createRequest (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/index.js:232:39)
at Object.Appc.createRequest (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/index.js:93:9)
at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/auth.js:266:8
at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3861:9
at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
at replenish (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:941:25)
at iterateeCallback (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:931:17)
at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3858:13
at /Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/auth.js:494:3
at next (/Users/kamrezvani/.appcelerator/install/6.2.4/package/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js:988:9)
<p class="p1">---------------------------------------------
at /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/iphone/cli/hooks/install.js:117:8
at /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3047:16
at replenish (/Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:982:17)
at /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:986:9
at eachLimit$1 (/Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3133:22)
at Object.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1016:16)
at /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/iphone/cli/hooks/install.js:105:11
at /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/device.js:65:11
at /Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-ios-device/ios-device.js:93:4
at Immediate.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/Users/kamrezvani/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.2.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-ios-device/ios-device.js:92:11)
at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
-- End application log -------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you have any 'backendless.js' file in your app->libs folder? If yes, then can you show its content or give a link to preview it?

Comment: Here is the requested link: http://api.backendless.com/sdk/js/latest/backendless.js
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the file you shared in your comment, it seems that you cannot use that code in Titanium apps because it's meant to be for web-site, not for mobile apps.

Moreover, that code is requiring further modules, out of which the first call in require is for **"stream module"** as you can see this snippet **`...module.exports = factory(require("stream")...`** in that code in top-lines.

Please aware of the fact that you are running the code in mobile apps, so every bit of code must be known for targeted mobile OS & here that **`backendless.js`** code is for web-sites.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following library to interface Appcelerator Titanium to Backendless:

[Backendless JS-SDK Patch for Appcelerator](https://github.com/Backendless/backendless-appcelerator)